# Interface inheritance without generics

Tags: delphi, inheritance, interface, delphi-2006

I am trying to implement an interface to convert records in a dataset to Delphi records in a pre-generics version of Delphi. I don't like the interface at the moment, as it will always need calls to Supports which I'd like to avoid if possible and was wondering if there's a better way of doing it that I'm missing.

So far I have an navigation interface and data retrieval interface defined:

```
IBaseRecordCollection = interface
  procedure First;
  procedure Next;
  function BOF: boolean;
  ... // other dataset nav stuff
end;

IRecARecordCollection = interface
  function GetRec: TRecA;
end;

IRecBRecordCollection = interface
  function GetRec: TRecB;
end;
```

Basically I have a concrete base class that contains a private dataset and implements `IBaseRecordCollection` and concrete class for each RecordCollection interface which derives from an abstract class implementing the `IBaseRecordCollection` (handled by an `implements` property) with the implementation of the record retrieval routine:

```
TAbstractTypedRecordCollection = class(TInterfacedObject, IBaseRecordCollection)
private
  FCollection: IBaseRecordCollection;
protected
  property Collection: IBaseRecordCollection read FCollection implements IBaseRecordCollection;
public
  constructor Create(aRecordCollection: IBaseRecordCollection);
end;

TRec1RecordCollection = class(TAbstractTypedRecordCollection, IRecARecordCollection);
public
  function GetRec: TRecA;
end;
```

Now, to use this I'm forced to have a builder that returns a `IRecARecordCollection` and then mess around with `Supports`, which I'm not keen on as it will always be used in this fashion.

i.e.

```
procedure GetMyRecASet;
var
  lRecARecordCollection: IRecARecordCollection;
  lRecordCollection: IBaseRecordCollection;
begin
  lRecARecordCollection := BuildRecACollection;
  if not supports(lRecARecordCollection, IBaseRecordCollection, lRecordCollection) then 
     raise exception.create();
  while not lRecordCollection.EOF do
  begin
    lRecARecordCollection.GetRec.DoStuff;
    lRecordCollection.Next;
  end;
end;
```

Although this works, I'm not keen on the `supports` call and mixing my lRecordCollections and my lRecARecordCollections like this. I had originally hoped to be able to do something like:

```
IBaseRecordCollection = interface
  // DBNav stuff
end;

IRecARecordCollection = interface (IBaseRecordCollection)
  function GetRec: TRecA;
end;

TRec1RecordCollection = class(TInterfacedObject, IRecARecordCollection)
private
  FCollection: IBaseRecordCollection;
protected
  property Collection: IBaseRecordCollection read FCollection implements IBaseRecordCollection;
public
  function GetRec: TRecA;
end;
```

but unfortunately Delphi wasn't smart enough to realise that the implementation of IRecARecordCollection was split over the base `IBaseRecordCollection` in the Collection property `implements` call and the TRec1RecordCollection object.

Are there any other suggestions for neater ways to acheive this?

-- edit to give a (longer) reply to @David's answer than possible in a comment

The suggested solution of:

```
IBaseRecordCollection = interface ['{C910BD0A-26F4-4682-BC82-605C4C8F9173}']
  function GetRecNo: integer;
  function GetRecCount: integer;
  function GetFieldList: TFieldList;
  function EOF: boolean;
  function BOF: boolean;
  ...
end;

IRec1RecordCollection = interface (IBaseRecordCollection) ['{E12F9F6D-6D57-4C7D-AB87-8DD50D35DCA2}']
  function GetRec: TRec1;
  property Rec: TRec1 read GetRec;
end;

TAbstractTypedRecordCollection = class(TInterfacedObject, IBaseRecordCollection)
private
  FCollection: IBaseRecordCollection;
protected
  property Collection: IBaseRecordCollection read FCollection implements IBaseRecordCollection;
public
  constructor Create(aRecordCollection: IBaseRecordCollection);
end;

TRec1RecordCollection = class(TAbstractTypedRecordCollection, IRec1RecordCollection, IBaseRecordCollection)
private
  function GetRec: TRec1;
public
  property Rec: TRec1 read GetRec;
end;
```

isn't compiling. It's complaining that `TRec1RecordCollection` cannot find methods related to `IBaseRecordCollection`. I also tried moving the `Collection` property from Abstract to `Rec1RecordCollection` and redeclaring the property in `TRec1RecordCollection` all with the same result

Looking a bit deeper it appears that direct inheritance of a class implementing `IBaseRecordCollection` would work but Delphi can't handle doing it indirectly via a property using `implements`.

Comment: For completeness, as there appears to be a bug in the D2006 compiler (**A** bug????) that means that @David's solution below doesn't work I have had to chop out the dependency injection and just have all TRecXRecordCollections inherit from the concrete TBaseRecordCollection rather than TAbstractTypedRecordCollection

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is almost there. The implements directive in your code fails to compile because you only declared that your class implements the derived interface. As it stands, your class does not implement the interface that the implements directive refers to, namely `IBaseRecordCollection`. You might think that would be inferred from the inheritance but it is not.

To solve your problem you simply need to declare that `TRec1RecordCollection` implements both interfaces:

```
type
  TRec1RecordCollection = class(TInterfacedObject, IBaseRecordCollection, 
    IRecARecordCollection)
  ....
  end;
```

Make just the one small change and your code will compile.

**Update**

Your edit to the question changes this somewhat. The code in my answer does indeed compile, given the code in your original question. However, add any method into `IBaseRecordCollection` and the compile will not accept it.

The compiler should accept this code and the fact that it does not is because of a compiler bug. Modern versions of Delphi will accept the code in your update to the question.

Unless you upgrade your compiler you will not be able to make your intended design work.

Comment: Yes, but then I have to pass around the concrete implementation rather than the interface, surely? Doesn't this negate what we're trying to acheive with interfaces? Applying this with the two interfaces would still result in the `supports` code above where I get one interface from the builder and have to use `Supports` to get the other and it is this that I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: No, pass around IRecARecordCollection

Comment: Brilliant - I'll give it a go when I'm back in the office on Monday and accept if it works

Comment: See edit to question above - short version: it didn't compile

Comment: Right, now you are asking a different question. Given the code in the original question, the code in my answer compiles.

Comment: OK, it seems that there's a compiler bug. I do want to stress however, that the code in my answer does compile. It compiles even in old versions like Delphi 6. The code in your edited question is a little different though. And the code in your edit compiles in modern Delphi. It's time you gave up on the old Delphi that you are using.

Comment: I wish that was in my power to do so :-(, unfortunately I'm not the one holding the purse strings. I think I'm stuck with either implementing the interface in the abstract class and passing everything on to FCollection or putting the concrete implementation of IBaseRecordCollection into TAbstractTypedRecordCollection